# I've seen many conflicting answers online: For optical storage, does a pit represent a '1' bit or does a land represent a '1' bit?

Tags: memory, non-volatile-memory, storage, data-storage, optical

I've seen many conflicting answers online so:

When reading an optical disk, which one of these is true:

A 'pit' represents 1 and a 'land' represents 0

or

A 'pit' represents 0 and a 'land' represents 1

Comment: Either works - this would be a property of a particular *specification*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C.  None of the above.**

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio)

> The frames of channel data are finally written to disc physically in the form of pits and lands, with each pit or land representing a series of zeroes, and with the transition points—the edge of each pit—representing 1.

A change from pit to land (or land to pit) is a 1.

Consecutive pits (or consecutive lands) is a 0.

Comment: This is specific to CDDA; is it also the encoding used for data CDs? what about DVDs or BDs?

Comment: @Hearth:  As far as I know, all optical media use a similar scheme.

Comment: That would be a good addition to the answer, I think. Though... Even the weird ones like flopticals and laserdisc?

Comment: Hmmmpf.  "Laserdiscs" were analog.  "Flopticals" stored the data magnetically and only used the optics to follow the tracks.

Answer (score 2):

So actually, it’s neither. Allow me to introduce you to a new thing, not a pit, not a land, but a change. A change is what happens when a pit becomes a land or vice versa. **Anything that is flat on an optical imaging disc is a 0, but a change is a 1.** people sometimes say it is an edge of a pit or land, but i like to use the term change. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's no yes/no answer.   The usual optical disk data representation is NOT in
one-to-one correspondence with the data recorded, rather a CD (for instance)
eight-bit chunk of input is translated into a fourteen-bit group, and that
fourteen-bit group is burned onto the disk.   What convention you use for the
fourteen-bit group is irrelevant to the user (who only gets the eight-bit
decoded data back).

So, a single bit of input/output data doesn't correspond to a single feature on the
disk in any one-to-one correspondence.